# Can't convert 'binary' string to 'regular' string

Tags: php, string, binary

I'm reading from a file through 'file_get_contents'. After exploding the content, one of the elements is presented this way when I dump it:

```
dd($myVariable);
```

> b"Crédito"

I've read on the internet that this is some kind of 'binary' string, related to a PHP version 6 that never existed. But I simply can not find a way to convert it to a 'regular' string.

I thought they were somehow equivalent, but I can't even use it to compare to another string. For example, none of these will ever return true:

```
if ($myVariable == "Crédito") 
if ($myVariable === "Crédito")
if ($myVariable == b"Crédito")
if ($myVariable == (binary)"Crédito")
```

How can I convert it to a regular string?

Comment: Is that output from `var_dump`?

Comment: `b"Crédito"` is not valid PHP, you'd need it to be `'b"Crédito"'`. What does `var_dump` show, actually binary?

Answer (score 2):

For me, [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) helped. hope it will help someone else also

```
utf8_encode($string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to unpack the binary data into a readable string using the `unpack` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)

Example for a string:

```
$var = b"binary";
$unpacked = unpack("a*", $var); // "a*" stands for as much as NUL-padded strings as possible
var_dump($unpacked);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, string ist still marked as "b"

Answer (score -1):

```
mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8')
```