# PHP: How to save binary string in MySQL 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, binary-string

How can I convert this binary string:

```
b"iphonée@3,;= ÑÑñe x"
```

To normal string?

I really need to have that string as a normal string, and not as a binary string.

I am having problems saving in MySQL this binary string. If the CSV that I decode does not have ñ, é or any of this non usual characters, I dont have problem saving. But when one of this characters is set on a cell, the string appears to be binary string and I get an error when saving on MySQL this binary string.

I get this error:

```
QueryException {#1780
  #sql: "insert into `seller_product_languages` (`seller_product_id`, `lang`, `name`, `description`, `description_html`, `bullet_html`, `bullet`, `meta_keywords`, `default`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
  #bindings: array:11 [
    0 => 117
    1 => "es"
    2 => b"iphonée@3,;= ÑÑñe x"
    3 => "negro"
    4 => "negro"
    5 => null
    6 => ""
    7 => null
    8 => 1
    9 => "2020-03-02 18:40:56"
    10 => "2020-03-02 18:40:56"
  ]
  #message: b"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE9e@3,;...' for column 'name' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `seller_product_languages` (`seller_product_id`, `lang`, `name`, `description`, `description_html`, `bullet_html`, `bullet`, `meta_keywords`, `default`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (117, es, iphonée@3,;= ÑÑñe x, negro, negro, , , , 1, 2020-03-02 18:40:56, 2020-03-02 18:40:56))"
  #code: "HY000"
  #file: "/home/vagrant/Code/PROJECT/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
  #line: 664
  -previous: PDOException {#1779
    #message: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE9e@3,;...' for column 'name' at row 1"
    #code: "HY000"
    #file: "/home/vagrant/Code/PROJECT/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
    #line: 458
    +errorInfo: array:3 [
      0 => "HY000"
      1 => 1366
      2 => "Incorrect string value: '\xE9e@3,;...' for column 'name' at row 1"
    ]
```

All tables and columns are `'utf8mb4'` and collation `'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'`

Environment:
-PHP 7.2
-Laravel 5.5
-Ubuntu 18.04
-MySQL 5.7

Comment: That look like a utf encoded string! What makes you think its binary?

Comment: Because in a var_dump it shows with a b at the beginning like in the example I put. And this means "binary string". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749442/what-does-the-b-in-front-of-string-literals-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't convert 'binary' string to 'regular' string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420762/cant-convert-binary-string-to-regular-string)

Comment: No. I just tried it and I get the same binary string, in an array
`array:1 [
  1 => b"Ñandú info@domain.com"
]`

Comment: var_dump says it is a string?

Comment: var_dump answers this: `string '�and� info@domain.com' (length=21)`

Comment: Can you add a bit more context to this please? I'm pretty certain (and the manual seems to agree) that "binary" strings [are functionally identical to any other string](https://3v4l.org/C4uHP). The only version where that wouldn't be true is PHP 6, which was never released. But in any case, what is it that you want to do with the string that doesn't work? Why do you need to convert it?

Comment: Hello! I just added more context! Maybe now its much clearer. Thanks for the recommendation. Hope the information added can help solve it. Have a nice day

Comment: There is no code in this question. How can we determine what the problem is?

Comment: are you sure that b" is not a garbage character? I saw something similar once (started with b as well) and it was some sort of trailing space from a latin collated table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it changing all tables from utf8 to utf8mb4. And doing utf8_encode(..) to the string

Thank you all